# Is $\mathbb{P}_n^{-1}[x]$ a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $\mathbb{P}_n^{-1}[x]=\{a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_nx^n:a_0-a_1+\cdots+(-1)^na_n=0\}$.
>
> Is  $\mathbb{P}_n^{-1}[x]$ a vector space?

I took different values of $a_i$ for different polynomials such that they satisfy the condition $a_0-a_1+\cdots+(-1)^na_n=0$, and added them, I think that it does satisfy the condition for vector spaces. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, its closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: This is the **set of polynomials which are zero, or of degree at most $\mathbf n$** which have $-1$ as a root, or equivalently, **which are multiples of $x + 1$**. This should keep you going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P(x)$ is a polynomial with $\deg P(X)\leqslant n$, then$$P(x)\in\Bbb P_n^{-1}[x]\iff P(-1)=0.$$So,

- $\Bbb P_n^{-1}[x]$ is not empty, since the null polynomial belongs to it.
- If $P(x),Q(x)\in\Bbb P_n^{-1}[x]$, $(P+Q)(-1)=P(-1)+Q(-1)=0$.
- If $P(x)\in\Bbb P_n^{-1}[x]$ and $\lambda$ is a scalar $(\lambda P)(-1)=\lambda P(-1)=0$.

So, yes, $\Bbb P_n^{-1}[x]$ is a vector space, since it is a subspace of the space of all polynomials $P(x)$ such that $\deg P(x)\leqslant n$.

Answer (score 1):

To show to that is a vector space, it's enough to show that it's a vector subspace of $\mathbb{P}_n[x]$.
So you need to show that it's no-empty and closed under addition and scalar multiplication, which is easy to show.

Answer (score 0):

It is a $(n+1)-1=n$ dimensional subspace because it is the **kernel** of the following linear form described into the basis $(1,x,x^2,\cdots x^n)$ by:

$$\begin{cases}(a_0,a_1,\cdots a_n) \ & \ \to \ & \ a_0-a_1+\cdots+(-1)^na_n\\
P_n[x]  \ & \ \to \ & \ \mathbb{R}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Any comment on this solution ?